# IE doesn't respect <label> within <anchor>

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, anchor, label

So I just found out that IE (even the current 10 & 11) do not support labels within anchor tags...but DOES support onclick actions within said tag. Ran into this when I was updating a menu system and wanted to use labels to separate the menu description from the associated shortcut. The 'redirect/processing' modal window comes up fine, but then things just sat there.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" onclick="console.log('you clicked me')">
    <label>I am a first label</label>
    <label>Look @ me, I'm second!</label>
</a>
```

As I dived into this strange topic, I found that the whitespace between the labels behaved appropriately...only when I hovered over the label did my ability to href outta here went away.

So...what's the solution?

Comment: `<label>` elements label form controls. Clicking on them focuses the associated form control. I can't see how they are appropriate for use inside a link.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The content model of `<a>` is *Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.*. `<label>` is interactive content.

Comment: Good point about the <label> === interactive content...they simply came out of the box as inline-blocks. Appreciate the comments, but not the -1...it's still a fact...the real question is why it still allows for the bubbling of an onclick event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use spans...that's it...

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.theonion.com" onclick="console.log('you clicked me')">
    <span>I am another first label</span>
    <span>Look @ me, I'm another second!</span>
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bdGPB/1/