# How to vertical align this span element?

Tags: css

This should be very simple, and apologies if it's a duplicate. I can't get some text in a span to vertically align beside an icon.

Example:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box">
  <a>
    <span>Search</span>
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS I've tried:

Setting the span to `display: inline-block` and assigning padding and margin. This also moves the icon up.

Setting the link to `position: relative` and positioning the span. This causes the icon to move, as the span is now taken out of the flow.

Adjusting the `line-height` of the span. Again, this affects the icon.

Floating the span. This doesn't work.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm not very familiar with flex, would that be a solution? (Note I have to support very old browsers...)

Suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `<i>` an id (or class, I named it `#k`), then add this ruleset:

> ```
>   #k { vertical-align: middle; }
> ```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#k {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box">
  <a href='#/'>
    <span>Search</span>
    <i id='k' class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works exactly as I need. I was hoping for a solution that targeted the span, but if that's not possible I'll go with this. Thanks!

Comment: Bad solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854800/ie-doesnt-respect-label-within-anchor There's a reason for using spans.

Comment: @ovokuro You're welcome. If this answer is the best solution, click the green ✔ of this post.

Answer (score 3):

Add following css:

```
.box a i,
.box a span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box a i,
.box a span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box">
  <a>
    <span>Search</span>
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Apply `display: flex` property to `.box a` and use `align-items: center` (this will align your items vertically centered).

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.box {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box a span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box">
  <a>
    <span>Search</span>
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for an answer with flex. This doesn't seem to work for situations where the container - in this case .box -  is dynamic. Example: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/xRyVbo

Comment: @ovokuro Do you want to make them stick together (search text and icon)?

Comment: @ovokuro Updated my answer. Also updated the codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGZEoj Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks very much for the updated solution! I think that other solutions in this case will work ok without needing flex, which I'm concerned about for supporting old browsers. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can easily adjust the positioning of your text in the `span` if you first make it a block element, and then apply a float. Once this is done, you can apply `line-height` as you initially mentioned, but without affecting the icon.

Here is a JSFiddle to show what to do. Incredible easy, and you don't have to touch your original CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkjaa8c/

**Solution using Floats**

```
.box span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

And you can change the float from left to right if you want the text on the right. Additionally, you can apply left and right padding to push the text away from the icon if you so desire: https://jsfiddle.net/rz4y4696/

```
.box span {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Additionally, I advise against using flex. People are constantly pushing flex as a solution, but it eliminates many legacy browsers from support. This would be one of the more traditional ways of implementing this, with fully cross browser, and legacy browser support.

---

**Solution without using Floats**

If you want a solution that does not require floats, and will work for varying widths, then you'd have to remove the `<i>` tag and add your `FontAwesome` icon to your CSS. You can see the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/rwkypte8/2/

You can get the value of the FontAwesome search icon here: http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/

The HTML and CSS is below:

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box">
  <a>
    <span>Search</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box span:after {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 30px;
  content: '\f002';
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. The only issue is that if the width of the box is dynamic, for example uses a percentage value, then the span will move position. And adding padding to left and right of the span won't correct this. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/rwkypte8/

Comment: You are correct, but that was not mentioned in your post in which you have a fixed width for your block element. But this is a button, which typically will have a float either to the left or right. In these cases my solution still holds true. But if you have a dynamic width as you mention in your comment, then you'd have to use a different solution. I can provide such a solution, but again, that would be outside the realm of your question.

Comment: I'll put together a different solution for you that will still apply to my solution, but instead will disregard the use of `<i>` Give me 15 minutes. I have to respond to some emails.

Comment: Solution added that removes the `<i>` tag and adds the icon via CSS. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated solution. While I appreciate the idea of using the icon like that, I think it is a little more code than is necessary so I'll use one of the other solutions. Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting that you think this approach uses more code. When having 20 or 30 icons in an application, all you do is have your `.box span:after {}` main declaration, and then for each icon in the CSS all you add is `content: \1234';`, as in `span.search:after {content:'\f002';}` `span.refresh:after {content: '\f021';};`, etc. It is by far the most efficient way of adding icons to your site. It even eliminates additional HTML and you no longer have to include `aria-hidden="true"`. But if you feel another solution works better for you, that's fine.